# Not same result on the same command in script and out of the script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When i pass this command out of my script :

```
transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -l | awk '{ s = ""; for (i = 10; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print s }' | grep "\b\b" | tail -1
```

The result is :

```
Micro Pratique N°247 Avril 2017.pdf
```

But when i pass this command in my script and stock the result in a variable like this :

```
test=`transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -l | awk '{ s = ""; for (i = 10; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print s }' | grep "\b\b" | tail -1`
```

The result is not the same ! Here the script with "set -x" :

```
+++ transmission-remote -n transmission:transmission -l
+++ awk '{ s = ""; for (i = 10; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print s }'
+++ grep '\b\b'
+++ tail -1
++ test='Pratique N°247 Avril 2017.pdf '
```

Why it cuts my first word "Micro" ?

Here the result of `transmission-remote -n transmission:transmission -l` :

```
ID     Done       Have  ETA           Up    Down  Ratio  Status       Name
   1   100%    8.30 GB  Done         1.0     0.0    2.8  Seeding      Ghost In The Shell 2 Innocence 2003 MULTi VFF BluRay 1080p AC3 x264
  65   100%    4.86 GB  Done         0.0     0.0    2.9  Idle         WWE.RAW.2017.03.20.720p.HDTV.x264-Ebi.mp4
  71   100%    2.89 GB  Done         0.0     0.0    2.9  Idle         WWE.Smackdown.Live.2017.03.21.720p.HDTV.x264-Ebi.mp4
 106   100%    4.80 GB  Done         0.0     0.0    0.0  Seeding      WWE.RAW.2017.03.27.720p.HDTV.x264-Ebi.mp4
 107   100%    2.90 GB  Done         0.0     0.0    0.9  Idle         WWE.SmackDown.Live.2017.03.28.720p.HDTV.x264-NWCHD.mp4
 113     0%       None  Unknown      0.0     0.0   None  Idle         Micro Pratique N°247 Avril 2017.pdf
Sum:          23.75 GB               1.0     0.0
```

Comment: Use `"$(transmission` ... `tail -1)"` (with `"$()"` instead of backquotes) and see if it works.  `$()` handled embedded quotes much more cleanly than backquotes do, and the extra `""` makes it so your output stays together.

Comment: There are several reasons to use `$(...)` instead of backquotes, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: Same result with $()

Comment: @Spread: can you post the complete output of `transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -l` for us to reproduce it locally?

Comment: What is `grep "\b\b"` supposed to be filtering?

Comment: The `transmission-remote` command may be altering its output depending on whether its standard input is a terminal or not. Compare the output of the command by itself at the prompt with the contents of `foo=$(transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -l)`; the number of fields may be different.

Comment: @Inian Yep it's good idea, it's ok now

Comment: Note that for a download with 0% progress the count of "fields" is less by 1 (`None` instead of `0 GB`). Hence the lost word in your filename.

Comment: @chepner the `"\b\b"` remove the empty lines

Comment: @Leon Yes ! You have right, it's the problem, now i have to find a solution

Comment: @Spread: Can you see if my answer helped!

Comment: Looking at your example data, it makes perfect sense seeing that the tenth field, ie. where your loop starts, on that line is the string 'Pratique'.  So my guess would be that when you ran it before, there must have been an additional field allowing 'Micro' to be the tenth field.  this would show that guessing the number of fields is the wrong method

Answer (score 2):

your file is fixed-width format, not properly delimited.  You can utilize `gawk`'s `FIELDWIDTHS` variable.  Since the other `awk`s don't support it, 
here is another approach, assuming you know the header of the field you're trying to extract

```
awk 'NR==1        {p=match($0,"Name")} 
     length($0)>p {print substr($0,p)}' file

Name
Ghost In The Shell 2 Innocence 2003 MULTi VFF BluRay 1080p AC3 x264
WWE.RAW.2017.03.20.720p.HDTV.x264-Ebi.mp4
WWE.Smackdown.Live.2017.03.21.720p.HDTV.x264-Ebi.mp4
WWE.RAW.2017.03.27.720p.HDTV.x264-Ebi.mp4
WWE.SmackDown.Live.2017.03.28.720p.HDTV.x264-NWCHD.mp4
Micro Pratique N°247 Avril 2017.pdf
```

to get the last entry record either `tail` or

```
awk 'NR==1        {p=match($0,"Name")} 
     length($0)>p {last=substr($0,p)} 
     END          {print last}' file

Micro Pratique N°247 Avril 2017.pdf
```